# Mapbox style to separate overlapping lines

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl

Given two linestrings that occupy the same space, is it possible to define a style such that the lines are offset from each other and are rendered side-by-side?

A colleague says he can half remember that this functionality is available in the [style spec](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/), but I have not been able to find reference to it. Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The property you are looking for is "Line-Offset".

From documentation ([paint-line-line-offset](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#paint-line-line-offset) as of 2018-09-17) :

> line-offset (Paint property) Optional number. Units in pixels. Defaults to 0. Transitionable.
>
> The line's offset. 
>   For linear features, a positive value offsets the line to the right, relative 
>   to the direction of the line, and a negative value to the left. 
>   For polygon features, a positive value results in an inset, and a negative value results in an outset.

Comment: When I first looked over this property, I didn't think it suited my needs. You prompted me to take another look at it, and it is actually what I need. Cheers

Comment: can this be done automatically by the mapbox engine? without having to manually offset a line, but instead it detects overlaps and offsets them for you